# Apache LDAP (Active Directory) not working

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, ldap

I've had some mixed success with Apache and LDAP.  First, it is working.. but not entirely.

So, a basic LDAP config, it looks like this:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "omitting this"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "passwordyeah!"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DOMAIN.COM/ou=stuff,dc=domain,dc=com?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
LDAPReferrals Off
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Use your email address to connect."
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthUserFile /dev/null
```

This is actually fine.  Here's where things get strange. If I put this:

```
Require user my@email.com
```

I can authenticate.  I can use multiple users, and it's fine.
If I put

```
Require valid-user
```

Authentication doesn't work.
If I try Domain Users, I get failures. (which all users are part of)

```
Require ldap-group CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
```

However, if I point to a smaller group, it works.

So, when I authenticate with just require user my@email.com I see this:

```
AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting my@email.com
```

When I put "Require valid-user" I get the *exact* same message.  However, the authentication dialog box comes up repeatedly. Each time, the authentication is successful (according to the logs)

For log purposes. When i require ldap "Domain users" I get this in the logs:

```
didn't match with attr member [Comparison false (adding to cache)][5 - Compare False]
```

(Understand this group is huge, as well)
When I use a smaller group, the logs show me success like this:

```
authorization successful (attribute member) [Comparison true (adding to cache)][6 - Compare True]
```

I'm just not really sure what is going on here. But I would really like "valid-user" to just work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the search base is ou=stuff,dc=domain,dc=com prevents objects in other containers from being found. Try setting the base only to dc=domain,dc=com

You can drop the objectclass=user filter too. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx userprincipalname is only used in the user class, so it's implicit. In that same page you can read that it's available throught the global catalog port, so you can use that instead of the normal ldap binding (should be faster).

So your AuthLDAPURL would then be:

AuthLDAPURL ldap://DOMAIN.COM:3268/dc=domain,dc=com?userPrincipalName?sub

Which looks a lot like the example in the 'Using Active Directory' section of the mod_authnz_ldap module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html

A last word of caution: you use the domain.com srv host notation (kuddos!), but Apache has not knowledge of AD sites. So if you have several sites and the network latencies are high, you could be querying a ldap server far away and taking a long time for authenticating.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the search base to the specific OU my user is in, and it still fails with "require valid-user". I extended the search base to the top level domain, but still fails with "domain users". Something is definitely not working right.

Comment: so what is the base now?

Comment: Well, I just tested and indeed, cn=Domain Users,cn=Users,$domain is not working, and that is possibly a bug in the ldap module, but ...., who cares? Unless you have modified the users' primary group (something I have never seen done in production environments) *all* users are members of 'domain users'. So the solution is simple: use the require valid-user directive in your apache configuration. I have just tested it, it works perfectly fine provided your base and search scopes are correct. I also tested with another very large group (>4000 users) and the require ldap-group worked as well

Comment: It's normal for AD to not match users against the Domain Users group. That is because AD at some point had a limitation on group size and the Domain Users group would often exceed that. As a consequence the membership to the primary group is expressed via the primaryGroupID user attribute (which contains the last part of the group SID) and not the memberOf / member attributes.